# Difference between two cells _VBA Excel Mac 2011

Tags: vba, excel

I want to subtract the days (TodayDate - ViolationDate) and save the answer in Difference column. Taking into account that the user will only enter the violation date. Once the user press the command button, it will show the answer.

I have used this code but it is not giving me the answer.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = TextBox1.Text

Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Date


Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, -1).Value - Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0,-2).Value

End Sub
```

Please Help. Thank You very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(, 3).Value = Array(TextBox1.Text, Date, Date - CDate(TextBox1.Text))

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to be more specific than "not working" please. What happens **exactly**?

Comment: Then I suspect whatever you are putting in the textbox is not recognisable as a date using your regional settings.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and it worked fine

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = TextBox1.Text
Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Date
Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = (Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value - Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Value)
End Sub
```